# (Hay alguna manera de enviar Variables a un Script) - Game Maker Studio 2 - GML

Tags: funciones, variables, script, game, game-maker

En otros lenguajes cuando se trabaja con una función, ésta se escribe...

```cpp
public void funcion_ejemplo(int variable1, int variable2){
  // la función trabaja con las vaiables que reciba
}
```

Entonces cuando yo deseo usar esta función lo llamaría y le mandaría datos, así:

```cpp
funcion_ejemplo(12,5);
```

*De ésta manera yo mando variables a ésta función para que ésta se ejecuta con variables distintas.*

Ahora en GameMakerTenemos los Scrips, las cuales las llamamos:

```cpp
Create_bomba();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

.
Habrá alguna manera de mandarle variables a éste script?
.
En caso no encuentre la manera, estaba pensado crear variables globales,y que los scripts usen éstas variables globales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El caso de los *scripts* es similar a las funciones ... pero no igual.

Como se indica en [la documentación](http://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/3_gml_overview/3_scripts.html), los *scripts* pueden recibir argumentos:

> When you create a script the values that you choose to pass into it are called arguments and you'll want to access these arguments - either when using the script action, or when calling the script as a function from a program or from another script.

Traducción libre por mi parte:

> Cuando se crea un script, los valores que elige pasar se llaman argumentos y querrá acceder a estos argumentos, ya sea al usar la acción de *script* o al llamar al *script* como una función desde un programa o desde otro *script*.

Si seguimos leyendo, llegamos al punto clave:

> These arguments are stored in the built-in variables: `argument0`, `argument1`, ... up to `argument15`.

Traducción mía:

> Estos argumentos se almacenan en las *variables integradas*: `argument0`, `argument1`, ... hasta `argument15`.

Es decir, a los argumentos se accede de una forma un tanto especial. El lenguaje incorpora 15 variables predefinidas para acceder a ellos:

```
if !is_real(argument0)
{
   return 0;
}
else
{
   return (argument0 * argument0);
}
```

Quedan mas cosas sobre los argumentos: variable integrada `argument`, función [`argument_count`](http://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/3_gml_overview/argument_count.html), ... A [la documentación](http://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/3_gml_overview/3_scripts.html) me remito.